# How to determine the order files are written to disk

Tags: c#, file, datetime, timespan, hl7

I have a issue where I am receiving HL7 messages that are being written to disk. The problem is the two messages are being sent within the same millisecond and I need to determine which one came across first and which one was second. I have created this code to do this and it for the most part works. Sometimes though it fails and I get a value of zero for the ticks value of the timespan object.

```
DirectoryInfo d_messages = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("AllRecievedHL7"));
d_messages.Refresh();
FileInfo[] messages = d_messages.GetFiles();

DateTime Message1 = messages[0].CreationTime;
DateTime Message2 = messages[1].CreationTime;
TimeSpan t_Test = Message1.Subtract(Message2);

 if (t_Test.Ticks > 0)
{
 //Message2 arrived before Message1
}
else
{
 //Message1 arrived before Message2
}
```

Does anyone know a way to determine this in such a way it will never fail?

Comment: If they have the same timestamp then you can only tell based on the content of the file or the naming of the file. The process that writes the message to disk should be responsible for ensuring that sort order should be easy to be determined if it is critical to reading the content of the message.

Comment: File times simply don't have that accuracy. You don't need to calculate the difference between two DateTime values either, just compare them directly. If you want to determine the message order, make sure you store file names with a name that incorporates an increasing suffix

Comment: The suggestions were valid. Since I wrote the listener receiving the messages, I was able to add a flag for this one test case, and simply add a pause to when the messages were written to disk and closed. Then it never failed. Simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wrote the interface receiving these messages all I did to solve this was add a sleep. I set a flag when this specific test was running and added this line between the messages received. Worked perfectly for me.

Thread.Sleep(500);